# Cite multiplie from biblograghy

Tags: apa-style, apacite

I am trying to site multiple references in using `\usepackage{apatite}` such as:

To keep up with the growing processing power demanded of today’s quantum computing world, and to utilize the newly available printable surface area, additional components need to be installed `\cite{church13;shinbo10}`.

So that it cites as ...(Church et al (2013); Shinbo & Hank (2010)).

I can get it to work as ...`\cite{church13}\cite{shinbo10}` but it shows as (ref1)(ref2).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times new roman,double space,scrreprt]{article}
%basic
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{setspace} %Sets double space

%Notes and quotes package
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}
\newcommand{\cmmnt}[1]{}

\title{Etch Protocols for UW-Stout Plasma Reactors}

\author{me
\thanks{thank yous}
}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing

To keep up with the growing processing power demanded of today’s quantum computing world, and to utilize the newly available printable surface area, additional components need to be installed \cite{church13;shinbo10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a comma instead of a semicolon?

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work before! Thank you!

Comment: I will post a answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma instead of a semicolon:

```
\cite{church13, shinbo10}
```